# Shopify Fetch Quantity Change in Cart from /cart/change.js

Tags: javascript, shopify

So basically I have this code for my a Shopify cart that fetches the SKU and quantity of each product from /cart.json, then appends each to a URL. However, when someone updates the quantities of the Shopify cart, the updated quantities are posted to /cart/change.js. I need to fetch this file the rerun my function using the updated quantities from /cart/change.js instead of /cart.json. Issue is I've tried fetching /cart/change.js and can't.

I would think the logic would be to run my function using the data from /cart/change.js when/if it loads.

Here's the current JS:

```
function updateCartButton() {

  // Fetch Cart JSON from Shopify
  const cartJson = '/cart.json';
  async function getCartJson() {
    fetch(cartJson)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })

      .then((data) => {

        // Get Product Info from Shopify
        let productInfo = data.items;
        console.log(productInfo);

        // Create URL Params Array
        let urlParamsArray = [];

        const createURL = () => {
          productInfo.forEach(object => {
            const urlParams = `${object.sku}.${object.quantity}`;
            urlParamsArray.push(urlParams);
          })
        }
        createURL()
        console.log(urlParamsArray);

        // Join URL Params into One String
        let urlParamsJoin = urlParamsArray.join('_');
        console.log(urlParamsJoin);

        // Get Checkout Button from Cart
        const checkoutBtn = document.querySelector('.cart__submit');
        console.log(checkoutBtn);

        // Add URL Params to Checkout Button
        checkoutBtn.onclick = () => {
          location.href = `https://cleannutra.pay.clickbank.net/?cbitems=` + `${urlParamsJoin}`;
        }
      });
  }
  getCartJson();
}
updateCartButton();
```

Comment: Can't you just rereun the function after change.js has been called? I'm not sure I understand the problem. `cart.js` aways return the content of the cart.

Comment: @FabioFilippi Each time the user updates the quantity of the cart, the data (such as quantity) goes to change.js, not cart.json. So I need pull that updated data after someone updates the quantity. Unless I'm missing something? Which is very possible since I'm new to JS and Shopify :)

Comment: @FabioFilippi any chance you could still help me out with this?

Comment: Hi @mkaskie change.js also return the json of the cart. What I said in my first comment remains valid.